# MongoDB error : DNSProtocolError: Incorrect record format for "": expected SRV record, found something else

Tags: mongodb

I have just set up a MongoDB account with a free hosted cluster.
I want to connect to my cluster through the command line but I am getting this error message :

> DNSProtocolError: Incorrect record format for "": expected SRV record, found something else

To sum up what I have done:
I just went into my online account and clicked on "Connect with Mongo Shell"; they give me a command that I should copy and paste in my command line :

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://testcluster-jqeq3.mongodb.net/test" --username admin
```

So I entered this command in my command line but it gives the here-above error.
Can someone help me please?

Here is the full trace of the command line:

```
C:\Users\Conserto>mongo "mongodb+srv://testcluster-jqeq3.mongodb.net/test" --username admin
DNSProtocolError: Incorrect record format for "": expected SRV record, found something else
```

Comment: 1) Which version of MongoDB ? 2) Could you connect using the standard URI format (not srv) ?

Comment: 1) Actually I was not using the right command. This one is for v3.6 and my Mongo version was v3.4. I used the right command and it is solved now.

Comment: Great to know it's resolved for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was not using the right command. This one is for v3.6 and my Mongo version was v3.4. I used the right command and it is solved now.